# ReactJs - best way to call redux action in useEffect

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have one component that fetch articles with axios, I want to retrieve the articles only in the first load of the url

```
useEffect( () => { 
    const getArticles = ()=>{
         dispatch(getArticlesAction())
   }   
    getArticles()
  }, [])
```

This way works perfectly, but I read some documentation I can have the same result with this:

```
useEffect( () => {    
    dispatch(getArticlesAction())
  }, [dispatch])
```

Using this also works without problems, I am passing the dispatch as dependency of useEffect, so my question is what is the best way to fetch the articles on the first load of the page? Thank you.

Comment: 2nd once was good practise. For first one you are declaring the `getArticles` function inside the `useEffect`. That not a good. Because `useEffect` is best fit for call the function instead of declaring function

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I don't know who gave -1 to my question, I am new to reactjs so I didn't know the best approach to accomplish that. other question, is it required to add dispatch as dependency? I tried the 2nd one with an empty array and still works. Thank you.

Comment: not necessary. `useEffect` rerun depend on dependency changes. But dispatch is function so is won't changed on future. That why if you either use it or not . it doesn't make any different

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both of these are technically pretty much equivalent. Technically you do not need to put `dispatch` into the dependency array as there is a good chance it will stay referentially equal for the lifetime of your application (unless you suddenly change out the store, which should not happen).

You should be using eslint with the official react-eslint plugin though (you might need to enable the eslint plugin in your editor), and that will warn you that you need to add dispatch. Since it doesn't hurt to do so, I'd recommend to go with it.